# Unable to download from multiple sites with uGet

Tags: connection, uget

I've downloaded uGet with aria2 and everything works fine when I only download from one server. When I activate Aria plugin to download from more than one server connections a get this messages and the download never start.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are downloading the same file multiple times...uGet will not do that...it will recognize that you already have it and immediately say it is done because you already have it.

You need to test this on a new file or delete the existing file to see it working.

### Edited on March 7th, 2014:

**Now that I've revisited this issue it looks as though you don't actually have aria2 installed. For more information about the aria2 plugin please go to http://ugetdm.com/downloads-aria2**

Comment: The second repeated file I was retrying the download.... thats not the problem. it works when has one server connection

Comment: You can't force a server to except multiple connections, servers have the ability to block multiple connections and even slow down speeds if they detect multiple connection attempts. Without knowing what you are downloading and from where there is no way to explain the issue.

Comment: OK I agree with you but, I think even if the site doesn't accept multiple connection should at least download using one connection

Comment: but it is already downloaded so I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I've updated the picture you can see there that the file wasn't downloaded. One second after being added that message appears

Comment: Do you have the aria2 plugin activated? If so do you have aria2 installed in your system? (you have to install aria2 separately from uGet)

Comment: Yes, have the latest version

Comment: take a screenshot of your aria2 plugin settings and link it here. Also did you install uGet from the Repo or from the official PPA or official DEB file?